Borg backup via Vorta: Stymied on connecting via ssh to remote repo
Setup: Borg & Vorta noob; competent beginner with command line. Borgbackup installed on local client (MacOS 10.14) and on remote server (Debian 12). Vorta 0.8.7 installed on Mac (not sure whether any later version will run on OS 10.14.6).
Progress so far: On Mac localhost command line, I successfully executed
borg init --encryption=repokey-blake2 my_remote_username@server_ip:backup_folder
and the new repo is now on my remote server in ~/backup_folder.
Stymied: In Vorta on my local Mac, I can't connect to the remote repo. When I type into Repository URL ssh://my_remote_username@server_ip:backup_folder and my enter my repo's passphrase, I get: ERROR: Connection closed by remote host.
I've tried generating an ssh key (which I don't really know how to do): On localhost I've got ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub. To store the public key on the remote server I executed cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh USER@HOST "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys", and on the remote server there is now a corresponding ~/.ssh/authorized_keysid_rsa file.
Tried again to connect to remote server (with default "Automatically choose SSH Key" setting), but still Vorta throws the same error.
I tried having Vorta init a repo on the remote server: same Repo URL as above (except different repo folder name), and in the "Advanced" tab I selected the ssh key I'd created. Same connection error.
I'm sure this must be user error. Appreciate any help.

The file where you public key is must be ~/.ssh/authorized_keys , not ~/.ssh/authorized_keysid_rsa

Also, when you connect to SSH, you will be was asked about SSH key passphrase, not the "repository passphrase". Generally you should check your key with ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 my_remote_username@server_ip, and if it appears to have a passphrase, you need to enter it every time you use this repo, or have a ssh agent running to store unencrypted private key (if Vorta is able to use agent, that is), or decrypt the key (with ssh-keygen) and limit it as recommended in the Borg manual (attach a forced borg serve command to the entry in the remote authorized_keys file).

This -- ~/.ssh/authorized_keys , not ~/.ssh/authorized_keysid_rsa -- did the trick (thank you, Romeo Ninov). And ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 my_remote_username@server_ip worked like a charm to confirm that the key worked on its own with no passphrase required (thank you, Nikita Kipriyanov).
